# Is there a way to build this alternative sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make the main content of webpage dynamic (change when links are clicked), but keep the sidebar static? I don't know if I am explaining this clear enough. If I'm still ambiguous in any way or form, please don't hesitate to ask.

The following site is a good example of what I am trying to achieve:
http://www.critocapital.com/investors

Comment: `position: fixed` basically. But you are supposed to do at least some basic research before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way is to create different pages with the same sidebar.

Alternately you should learn something about ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

you can find several informations about ajax on w3school too

or use iframes

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp